# Need xpath to iFrames located in 3rd and 4th <tr> tags in . <Div><tr><tr><tr><tr></Div>

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Hi I tried the following and it finds the first `iframein tr3` and enters the text but not sure how to access the next iframe in 4th `<tr>` tag to enter my text.

The following works but only accesses the 3rd `<tr>` which is the first place that has my iFrame in it

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id, '_ifr')]")));
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("tinymce")).SendKeys("Your Text Here");
```

**FACT: I DO have a static ID in `Div` tag though** so the above code may not be the correct way to do it access the iFrames in the 3rd and 4th `<tr>`

any thoughts please ?

Using switch in the above code I was able to access the desired iframe in 3rd `<tr>` but now I want to access the iframe in 4th `<tr>`

I also tried using
`Switch.default` and then

```
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@id, '_ifr')]")));
```

after accessing the first iframe, but this reselected the iframe in tr3 again

Comment: can you share the url?